# Solr facet count not matching results count due to synonym results

Tags: solr

I am running into an issue where I need to match the facet count to the query results count. The problem is that the facet count only matches the searched term, but not the count of results that match the synonyms. For example, I am getting 236 as the facet count, but the results count is 338. Is there a schema setting to include the synonym results in the facet count?

Comment: If you specify `facet.query`, check if it correctly includes the corresponding field and if it corresponds to the actual query which bring you these 338 results.